# Problema de leitura e inserção de dados no arquivo DBF após a exclusão de todos os registros

Tags: c#

Estou criando um sistema que vai ler um arquivo `xls`, excluir os dados de um arquivo `dbf` para então incluir todos os registros do `xls` na tabela.

Porem, esse sistema é um sistema intermediário, pois os dados do `dbf` são utilizados em um sistema em VB.

O sistema intermediário está consultando o `xls`, gravando os dados em um `DataTable`, está excluindo os dados do `dbf` (inclusive está dando "PACK" para confirmar a exclusão dos dados) e insere novos registros no arquivo.

Estou utilizando o DBF Commander para verificar se os dados estão realmente lá. Mas quando abro o sistema e mando gerar uma consulta, ele não retorna nenhum registro e também não me permite inserir novos registros.

Estou colocando o código da exclusão, pois verifiquei que mesmo sem inserir um registro pelo meu sistema, deixando o `dbf` limpo, não consigo incluir novos registros

```
private void btnDeletar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Pergunta se deseja continuar
    if (clsGeneric.MsgDialog("Você está prestes a deletar a tabela. Deseja continuar?", "Cuidado!", clsGeneric.DialogType.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        // Instâncias
        string vStrFileTree;
        string vSql;
        OleDbConnection conn;
        OleDbCommand com;
        vStrFileTree = edtPathDBF.Text;

        // Busca do diretório
        string strDirectoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(vStrFileTree);
        string strTable = vStrFileTree.Replace(strDirectoryPath, "");
        strTable = strTable.Replace("\\", "");

        // Conexão para a alterar a flag de "registro deletado" do DBF [Não Exclui os dados]
        conn = new OleDbConnection(clsConnection.strConnectDBF(strDirectoryPath, "EXCLUSVE=YES;"));
        conn.Open();
        try
        {
            com = new OleDbCommand();
            com.Connection = conn;
            vSql = "DELETE FROM " + strTable;

            com.CommandText = vSql;
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
            conn = null;
            com = null;

        }

        // Regerando as conexões, fazendo o PACK do arquivo DBF [PACK - Exclusão Permanente dos dados deletados]
        conn = new OleDbConnection(clsConnection.strConnectDBF(strDirectoryPath, "EXCLUSVE=YES;"));
        conn.Open();
        try
        {
            com = new OleDbCommand();
            com.Connection = conn;

            com.CommandText = "PACK " + strTable;
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
            conn = null;
            com = null;
        }
    }
    getDBFTable(grdImpDBF, edtPathDBF, false);
}
```

Logo abaixo está o código da *string* de conexão:

```
public static string strConnectDBF(string Path, string Extended = "")
{
    vStrConn = "Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;";
    vStrConn = vStrConn + "Data Source=" + Path + ";";
    if (Extended != "")
    {
        vStrConn = vStrConn + Extended;
    }

    return vStrConn;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descobri qual era o problema. O problema era que ao alterar o arquivo .DBF, eu não estava reindexando a tabela no arquivo .CDX, desse modo o sistema principal não encontrava as informações no arquivo .DBF, só retornando os registros já indexados no .CDX.

Resolvi o problema criando uma rotina que excluía o arquivo .CDX, pois o sistema principal ao consultar os dados já criava o arquivo caso não existisse.